# How to convert from a Swift String Set to an Array

Tags: arrays, string, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to create an array of words from a string object retrieved from Parse. The object retrieved looks like this:

[image: img1]

Then this line of code gives this.

```
let joinedWords = object["Words"] as! String
```

[image: img2]

How do I convert joinedWords to an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @JAL for so much time on chat to solve this one. This is what we came up with. Its a bodge and no doubt there is a better way!

When uploading to Parse save the set as an array.

```
let wordsSet = (wordList?.words?.valueForKey("wordName"))! as! NSSet
                let wordsArray = Array(wordsSet)
```

Then it saves to Parse - looking like a set, not an array or a dictionary.

```
let parseWordList = PFObject(className: "WordList")
parseWordList.setObject("\(wordsArray)", forKey: "Words")
parseWordList.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
                    if succeeded {
                       // Do something
                    } else {
                        print("Error: \(error) \(error?.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
```

Then you can drop the [ ] off the string when its downloaded from Parse, and remove the , and add some "" and voila, there is an array that can be used e.g. to add to CoreData.

```
var joinedWords = object["Words"] as! String
joinedWords = String(joinedWords.characters.dropFirst())
                        joinedWords = String(joinedWords.characters.dropLast())
let joinedWordsArray = joinedWords.characters.split() {$0 == ","}.map{ String($0) } // Thanks @JAL!
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order, you can use `flatMap` on the set:

```
var mySet = Set<String>()

for index in 1...5 {
    mySet.insert("testwords\(index)")
}

let myArray = mySet.flatMap { $0 }

print(myArray) // "["testwords5", "testwords3", "testwords4", "testwords2", "testwords1"]"
```

If you want the list sorted alphabetically, you can make your array a `var` and use `sortInPlace()`

```
var myArray = mySet.flatMap { $0 }

myArray.sortInPlace()

print(myArray) // "["testwords1", "testwords2", "testwords3", "testwords4", "testwords5"]"
```

If `object["Words"]` is `AnyObject`, you will have to unwrap it.

```
if let joinedWordsSet = object["Words"] as? Set<String> {

    var joinedWordsArray = joinedWordsSet.flatMap { $0 }

    myArray.sortInPlace()

    print(myArray)

}
```

Swift 3 note: `sortInPlace()` has been renamed `sort()`.

Comment: ah, no it hasn't. I need to get the words that are in joinedWords string, not create a new set. How would I do that?

Comment: @richc It's not clear what you're asking.  From your screenshot it looks like `Words` is a set of Strings ("testwords1", "testwords2", ...).  Are you trying to create a string with all of these words?

Comment: joinedWords is a set of strings in the form { (testword1, testword2, testword3, testword4, testword5)}. I need to convert that to an array in the form ["testword1", "testword2", "testword3", "testword4", "testword5"]. Order is not important for now. There can be any number of words.

Comment: @richc Right, so that's what my answer does.  First declare `let joinedWords = object["Words"] as! Set<String>`, then call `flatMap` on `joinedWords` like this: `joinedWords.flatMap { $0 }` to flatten the set into an array.  If `object["Words"]` is not a Set, tell me what type it is by printing `object["Words"].dynamicType`.

Comment: print(object["Words"].dynamicType) gives ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AnyObject> in console. Declaring joinedWords as a Set<String> crashes with Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1e68da4) to 'NSSet' (0x1e697e0).

Comment: @richc I've edited my answer and added an example of how to unwrap this value from the dictionary into a Set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99849/discussion-between-richc-and-jal).